# Order of methods in R reference class and multiple files

Tags: r, oop, reference-class

There is one thing I really don't like about R reference class: the order you write the methods matters. Suppose your class goes like this:

```
myclass = setRefClass("myclass",
                       fields = list(
                           x = "numeric",
                           y = "numeric"
                       ))


myclass$methods(
    afunc = function(i) {
        message("In afunc, I just call bfunc...")
        bfunc(i)
    }
)

myclass$methods(
    bfunc = function(i) {
        message("In bfunc, I just call cfunc...")
        cfunc(i)
    }
)


myclass$methods(
    cfunc = function(i) {
        message("In cfunc, I print out the sum of i, x and y...")
        message(paste("i + x + y = ", i+x+y))
    }
)



myclass$methods(
    initialize = function(x, y) {
        x <<- x
        y <<- y
    }
)
```

And then you start an instance, and call a method:

```
x = myclass(5, 6)
x$afunc(1)
```

You will get an error:

```
Error in x$afunc(1) : could not find function "bfunc"
```

I am interested in two things:

- Is there a way to work around this nuisance?
- Does this mean I can never split a really long class file into multiple files? (e.g. one file for each method.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `bfunc(i)` isn't going to invoke the method since it doesn't know what object it is operating on!

In your method definitions, `.self` is the object being methodded on (?). So change your code to:

```
myclass$methods(
    afunc = function(i) {
        message("In afunc, I just call bfunc...")
        .self$bfunc(i)
    }
)
```

(and similarly for `bfunc`). Are you coming from C++ or some language where functions within methods are automatically invoked within the object's context?

Some languages make this more explicit, for example in Python a method with one argument like yours actually has two arguments when defined, and would be:

```
  def afunc(self, i):
  [code]
```

but called like:

```
  x.afunc(1)
```

then within the `afunc` there is the `self` variable which referes to `x` (although calling it `self` is a universal convention, it could be called anything).

In R, the `.self` is a little bit of magic sprinkled over reference classes. I don't think you could change it to `.this` even if you wanted.